# WebSocket messages stuttering every couple seconds

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, websocket

I'm trying to build a game which uses WebSockets. The collision detection and game state is handled on the server, which runs a game loop approx every 16ms. Each iteration, it sends out a message with the updated state to all players, which update the local copy and render the game.

About half the messages arrive fine, but sometimes there will be a batch where hundreds of ms of game time arrives instantly.

[image]

I created a minimal test case, which sends the current timestamp every 16ms. On the client, you can see it buffer messages every couple of seconds:

[image]

I've profiled the application, and over the duration of that gif there was only one dropped frame, with it otherwise maintaining a consistent 60fps.

[image]

I'm guessing GC could be the cause of one of the delays, but as for the others and resolving this I'm pretty stuck.

The application itself is Vue, however the game part is implemented in plain JS + Canvas.

Comment: Hey @Benedict did you ever figure out how to solve the problem? I am facing the same issue with browser multiplayer game where it seems sending 50kb packets 60 times per second to 4 clients causes massive lag. Maybe this is obvious to anyone who has developed games but it really is a bummer if I now have to engineer some kind of physics engine in client as well to calculate the positions and then reconcile with the server. With 10 frames per second it works ok, but yeah it's not very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Is your game loop using Window.requestAnimationFrame()? I would try to run the websocket code separetly, like in a timer.

You can also try other values for the websocket refresh like 36ms, 60ms, 120ms and see if this problem is still active. Maybe there are too many requests and some caching going on in the browser or in the server side.

I can't reprocude your problem, you should make sure this is because of the GC. (If this is the case you can try to eliminate the heavy GC calls (try reuse objects/arrays). Or maybe you can use your websocket code in a web worker somehow, but if the GC runs then the mainthread is blocked so you can put logic in the web worker also, but this is just a wild speculation, anyway you can test the communication in a webworker without game logic, just timestamps values).